# how to find one of the k smallest elements in n-k comparisions given that Array is unsorted and n is the size of the array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are given two inputs: an integer k, and an array A containing n integers.
Give an algorithm to find any one of the k smallest elements of A, using at most
n − k comparisons. (In other words, your algorithm must return one of the k
smallest elements of A, but it doesn’t matter which one.) Explain why your
algorithm is guaranteed to find a correct answer and why it satisfies the bound
on the running time. (Hint: there is a very easy way to solve this problem).

Comment: Taking this literally, you seem to want to find the largest element in either 1 or 0 comparisons. Are you sure you have read the question correctly?

Comment: hi @mcdowella I am pasting the question:
You are given two inputs: an integer k, and an array A containing n integers.
Give an algorithm to find any one of the k smallest elements of A, using at most
n − k comparisons. (In other words, your algorithm must return one of the k smallest elements of A, but it doesn’t matter which one.) Explain why your algorithm is guaranteed to find a correct answer and why it satisfies the bound on the running time.

Comment: You don't solve this problem by writing code. You solve this problem with a pencil and paper and thought. Start by describing how you'd find the smallest of two items. How many comparisons did that take? How about finding the second smallest of 3 elements? How many comparisons did that take? Do the same kind of thing for 4 and 5 elements. Can you draw a general conclusion from your results? After you've solved the problem on paper, *then* you can write code to implement your solution.

Comment: Hint: if you have found n-k elements that are larger as one you have stored, the stored element must be one of the k smallest.

Comment: I tried all the hints given above. Still having trouble

Comment: You are maybe thinking to complicated, the solution is really easy (almost trivial). Take a rest for a while and try again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For k=1 I can find the smallest element in n-1 comparisons - just go along the array and keep track of the smallest element seen so far.

For k=2 find the smallest element of the first n-1 elements in the array, using n-2 comparisons. This is the smallest element in the whole array unless the element you missed is smaller, in which case it is the second smallest, which is OK.

For general k, find the smallest element in the first n-k+1, neglecting the last k-1 elements in the array. The result is the smallest element unless up to k-1 of the remaining elements are smaller, in which case it is still among the k smallest elements, and you are OK.